# GnuPG can see a card under root user, but not under normal user

Tags: linux, gnupg, smartcard, openpgp

When under an unprivileged user:

```
$ gpg --card-status
gpg: selecting openpgp failed: No such device
gpg: OpenPGP card not available: No such device
```

With `sudo` or under a root user:

```
$ sudo gpg --card-status
Reader ...........: ...
```

Problem similar to [that circa 2011](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2011-August/042533.html).

Answer (score 3):

When comparing with a different card reader it is immediately obvious a permission problem.

```
$ getfacl /dev/bus/usb/003/021
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/bus/usb/003/021
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:sanmai:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Where for the problematic card reader there's no extra user permission:

```
$ getfacl /dev/bus/usb/003/020
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/bus/usb/003/020
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--
```

Under Debian-based these extra permissions are set by udev rules:

```
cat /lib/udev/rules.d/60-scdaemon.rules
```

These [rules can be extended](https://wiki.debian.org/udev) by adding a line to, say, `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-scdaemon-local.rules` with vendor and product IDs of the problematic reader:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="xxxx", ATTR{idProduct}=="yyyy", ENV{ID_SMARTCARD_READER}="1", ENV{ID_SMARTCARD_READER_DRIVER}="gnupg"
```

Then reloading the rules:

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```